# How to save all layers in a MXD with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, layers

I'm using this code and it does not work. I simply want to save the layer after I repair the source/symbology/etc without manually clicking, save as layer file and overwriting the file.

```
import arcpy

def layer_save(mxd_path):
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxd_path)
    fcs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
    for item in fcs:
        item.save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mxd_p = r"H:\Test\python_output\4test.mxd"
    layer_save(mxd_p)
```

Comment: Are you showing all the code? Where do you define mxd_path and what's calling the function layer_save()?

Comment: I edited the code to show everything

Comment: fixed, I'm getting an error 'global name 'lyr' is not defined'

Comment: replace lyr.save() with item.save()

Comment: Just tried item.save() and got error: <type 'exceptions.AssertionError'>: No filename set.

Comment: @Hornbydd, it would be good if you put that in an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you search the help file for the topic **Layer (arcpy.mapping)** as you actually want to be using [saveACopy()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000)! There is a subtle difference between *save* and *saveACopy* and how they behave depends entirely on how you got a handle on the layer. There is a code "Example 1" showing how it is done. The Desktop Help always provides code snippets, they are usually the first place you should go to see how to use arcpy for a specific tool/object.

Comment: While saveACopy() does work, it does puke if the layer is a group layer. Trying to figure out how to work with these now

Answer (score 0):

For your group layer issue, just check `item.isGroupLayer`

ESRI's documentation of the API is usually pretty good
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000008000000

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Your answer is certainly useful but for it to gain you reputation you may want to show how this would be applied to the code snippet in the question.  Answers of a few paragraphs are generally preferred over one or two liners.